# Recalculate column only for highest date in each category

Tags: r, data.table

I want to recalculate a column in my `data.table` only for certain rows, depending on a `Condition`, the category (`Cat`) and the `Date`.

A row may qualify to be recalculated only if `Condition==TRUE`. Among all rows with `Condition==TRUE`, only the rows with the highest `Date` for the respective `Cat` should be selected.

A simplified example:

```
     DF = data.frame(Cat=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=3), Date=rep(c("01-08-2013","01-07-2013","01-04-2013"),3),
            Condition=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
            Data1=c(1:9), Data2=rep(c(1:3),3), Result=c(1:1))
     DF$Date = as.Date(DF$Date , "%m-%d-%Y")
     DT = data.table(DF)
     DT

        Cat       Date Condition Data1 Data2 Result
     1:   A 2013-01-08      TRUE     1     1      1
     2:   A 2013-01-07      TRUE     2     2      1
     3:   A 2013-01-04     FALSE     3     3      1
     4:   B 2013-01-08     FALSE     4     1      1
     5:   B 2013-01-07     FALSE     5     2      1
     6:   B 2013-01-04     FALSE     6     3      1
     7:   C 2013-01-08     FALSE     7     1      1
     8:   C 2013-01-07     FALSE     8     2      1
     9:   C 2013-01-04      TRUE     9     3      1
```

I found out how to extract the `Cat`'s and `Date`'s of the rows, for which the `Result` must be recalculated:

```
    setkey(DT, Condition, Cat, Date)
    DT[J(TRUE), max(Date), by=Cat]

       Cat         V1
    1:   A 2013-01-08
    2:   C 2013-01-04
```

However, I don't know how to calculate a new `Result` for these rows.
In this simplified example, the new `Result` should be `Data1+Data2`.

**Edit:**
Inspired by eddi's answer, I came up with two more possible solutions:

Approach using `.I`:

```
    DT[DT[Condition==TRUE , .I[which.max(Date)], by=Cat][[2]], Result:=Data1+Data2]
```

Approach using `.SD` (see eddi's note of caution):

```
    max_dates=DT[Condition==TRUE , .SD[which.max(Date)], by=Cat]
    setkey(DT, Cat, Date)
    DT[max_dates, Result:=Data1 + Data2]
```

Are there any recommendations which solution to choose with regard to speed / efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
dt = data.table(DF)
max_dates = dt[Condition == TRUE,
               list(Date = max(Date), Condition = TRUE),
               by = Cat]

setkey(dt, Cat, Date, Condition)
dt[max_dates, Result := Data1 + Data2]
dt
#   Cat       Date Condition Data1 Data2 Result
#1:   A 2013-01-04     FALSE     3     3      1
#2:   A 2013-01-07      TRUE     2     2      1
#3:   A 2013-01-08      TRUE     1     1      2
#4:   B 2013-01-04     FALSE     6     3      1
#5:   B 2013-01-07     FALSE     5     2      1
#6:   B 2013-01-08     FALSE     4     1      1
#7:   C 2013-01-04      TRUE     9     3     12
#8:   C 2013-01-07     FALSE     8     2      1
#9:   C 2013-01-08     FALSE     7     1      1
```

*A note of warning:* the above relies on `max_dates` not having a key - if you change it to have a key (e.g. if you do a `by` by a column that's part of the key), then you'd have to either erase its key, or make it have the same key as `dt` later in the code for the merge to work correctly.

And here's another approach:

```
dt = data.table(DF)

dt[, Result := Result + (Data1 + Data2 - Result) * Condition * (Date == max(Date)),
     by = list(Cat, Condition)]
# I could've used ifelse here instead, but ifelse is slow
```